# FQL from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

What's the easiest way to perform an FQL query from an ASP.NET application? Do I have to download the Facebook Developer Toolkit (which I only want to use as a last resort), or is there an easier way (maybe through javascript)? I'm not doing any heavy queries if that makes a difference. (I simply want to get the user's profile picture URL from my site. It might not even need FQL?)

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could try this variant with jquery to make a call with [REST](http://www.highonweb.com/?p=459).
but as the fb developers state, it is the old variant to access fb ressources. instead they recommend  the usage of the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api). With it you could also access your profile image..

> > Pictures
>
> You can render the current profile
>   photo for any object by adding the
>   suffix /picture to the object URL. For
>   example, this will render your public
>   profile photo:
>
> < img src="https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture"/>
>    [image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise the Graph API was so easy to use. Scary in a way...but cool nevertheless...